# Preg_match_all patterns except

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get all occurrences of a specific tag from a text field, and retrieve only part of it's content

```
<h4>
TEXT TO RETRIEVE HERE
<br>
EVERYTHING ELSE
</h4>
```

The issue I have is that not in every case does a BR tag show up, so when it does, I want to exclude it + everything following it

```
<br>
EVERYTHING ELSE
```

I tried the following preg_match_all, but no luck:

```
preg_match_all('/<h4>(.*?)<br>.*<\/h4>/ims', $text, $match)
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion to use a regex for this? And why don't you elaborate on the properties of the contained string context? Is your example really representative of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Hello Mario, can you explain what you mean when you say I should elaborate on the properties of the contained string context? I mean, I have content I grab from a MYSQL DB TEXT field, I have multiple H4 entries within it in which I need to extract part of the content and display it differently. So yes a preg_match_all seems to be what makes more sense, unless you have something else to suggest that could be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this,

```
<h4>((?:(?!<br>).)*)(?=<br>|<\/h4>)
```

It captures the value after the `<h4>` tag which are not of `<br>` zero or more times. And it must be followed by a `<br>` tag or `</h4>` tag.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yI3iS2/6)

Comment: Thanks Avinash, your answer worked. I did have to modify `<br> with <br` because of multiple BR formatting but overall it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<h4>.*?(?=<br>|$)
```

with "dot matches line-break"  and ^$ don't match at line break options enabled

If you need to ensure that the closing tag exists at the end, you can try:

```
<h4>.*?(?=(?:<br>.*</h4>)|(?:</h4>))
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work, maybe cause the br tag is sometimes written br / and sometimes without the slash? And yes I do need to ensure there is a closing h4 tag cause there are many cases where BR does not exist... also keep in mind that there is more than 1 occurence of H4 per page and I have to get all of them

Comment: @PHPFever Well, without knowledge of the variability in your data, crafting a response is hit and miss.  I'm glad one of them "hit"